# Error in the deletion part of Student management system using linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have written this code for management system of student using linked list but its sorting and deleting the node part is not working.

Can anyone help me out?

It inserts the node, modifies it and searches it perfectly. But, when it comes to deletion and sorting, the program hangs as soon as we select the option to do that.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dos.h>

struct stud
{
int rn,id,ph;
 char add[30],na[20],d[15],in[10];
 struct stud *next;
}*h=NULL,*p,*q,*t;

void add()
{
clrscr();
p =(stud *)malloc(sizeof(stud));
printf("\nEnter first name of Student : ");
scanf("%s",&p->in);
printf("\nEnter the Last Name of Student : ");
scanf("%s",&p->na);
printf("\nEnter the ID of Student not more 
than 5 digits: ");
 scanf("%d",&p->id);
 printf("\nEnter the Roll No. of Student : ");
 scanf("%d",&p->rn);
 printf("\nEnter the Address of Student : ");
 scanf("%s",&p->add);
 printf("\nEnter the D.O.B. of 
Student(dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
 scanf("%s",&p->d);

  p->next=NULL;

 if(h==NULL)
 {
 h=p;
 }
 else
 {
 q=h;
  while(q->next!=NULL)
  q=q->next;
  q->next=p;
  }
 t++;
 }

void addAt(int r) 
{
 q=h;
while(q->rn!=r || q==NULL)
 q=q->next;
if(q->rn==r)
{
clrscr();
 p =(stud *)malloc(sizeof(stud));
printf("\nEnter first name of Student : ");
scanf("%s",&p->in);
printf("\nEnter the Last Name of Student : ");
scanf("%s",&p->na);
printf("\nEnter the ID of Student : ");
scanf("%d",&p->id);
printf("\nEnter the Roll No. of Student : ");
scanf("%d",&p->rn);
printf("\nEnter the Address of Student : ");
scanf("%s",&p->add);
printf("\nEnter the D.O.B. of 
Student(dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
 scanf("%s",&p->d);
 p->next=q->next;
 q->next=p;
 t++;
 }
else
{
printf("\n\nRecord Not Found.");
}
}


void delAt(int r)
  {
 q=h;
  while((q->next)->rn!=r || q==NULL)
  q=q->next;
   if((q->next)->rn==r)
   {
   q->next=(q->next)->next;
   printf("\n\nRecord Deleted.");
   t--;
  }
  else
   printf("\n\nRecord Not Found.");
   }

void modAt(int id)
{
q=h;
int ch;
while(q->id!=id && q!=NULL)
q=q->next;
if(q->id==id)
{
clrscr();
printf("*** MODIFY ***\n1.First name\n2.Last 
Name");
printf("\n3.Roll No.\n4.Add\n5.D.O.B.:\nEnter 
choice: ");
scanf("%d",&ch);
switch(ch)
{
case 1 :  printf("\n\nEnter first name of 
Student : ");
  scanf("%s",&q->in);break;
 case 2 :  printf("\nEnter the Last Name of 
 Student : ");
  scanf("%s",&q->na);break;
 case 3 :  printf("\nEnter the Roll No. of 
Student : ");
  scanf("%d",&q->rn);break;
 case 4 :  printf("\nEnter the Address of 
Student : ");
  scanf("%s",&q->add);break;
case 5 :  printf("\nEnter the D.O.B. of 
Student(dd/mm/yyyy) : ");
  scanf("%s",&q->d);break;
 }
 }
else
printf("\nRecord not Found.");
}

void search(char ni[5])
{
int flag=0;
q=h;
clrscr();
while(q!=NULL)
{
if(stricmp(q->in,ni)==0)
{
flag=1;
printf("\n\nInitals of Student :   %s ",q- 
>in);
printf("\n\nLast Name of Student : %s ",q- 
>na);
printf("\n\nID of Student :        %d ",q- 
>id);
 printf("\n\nRoll No. of Student :  %d",q- 
>rn);
printf("\n\nAddress of Student :   %s",q- 
>add);
printf("\n\nD.O.B. of Student :    %s",q->d);
 printf("\n\n\n");
 }
 q=q->next;
 }
 if(flag==0)
 printf("\n\nNo Match Found.");
 }

 void sort()
 {
 p=h;
 while(p!=NULL)
 {
 q=h;
 while(q!=NULL)
 {
 if(stricmp(q->in,(q->next)->in)>0)
  {
 strcpy(t->in,q->in);
strcpy(t->na,q->na);
 t->id=q->id;
t->rn=q->rn;
t->ph=q->ph;
strcpy(t->add,q->add);
strcpy(t->d,q->d);


strcpy(q->in,(q->next)->in);
strcpy(q->na,(q->next)->na);
q->id=  (q->next)->id;
q->rn=  (q->next)->rn;
q->ph=  (q->next)->ph;
strcpy(q->add,(q->next)->add);
strcpy(q->d,(q->next)->d);

strcpy((q->next)->in,t->in);
strcpy((q->next)->na,t->na);
(q->next)->id = t->id;
(q->next)->rn = t->rn;
(q->next)->ph = t->ph;
strcpy((q->next)->add,t->add);
strcpy((q->next)->d,t->d);

}
 q=q->next;
}
 p=p->next;
}

 }  

void disp() 
{
p=h;
clrscr();
while(p!=NULL)
 {
 printf("\nInitals of Student :   %s ",p->in);
 printf("\nName of Student :      %s ",p->na);
printf("\nID of Student :        %d ",p->id);
 printf("\nRoll No. of Student :  %d",p->rn);
  printf("\nAddress of Student :   %s",p- 
 >add);
 printf("\nD.O.B. of Student :    %s",p->d);
 printf("\n\n");
 p=p->next;
}  
} 

void main()
{
int ch=0,r;
char ni[5];
clrscr();
while(ch!=8)
{
clrscr();
 printf("1.Add the Record.\n\n2.Delete 
 Record.");
 printf("\n\n3.Modify Record.\n\n4.Search 
  Record.\n\n5.Sort Records.");
 printf("\n\n6.Display\n\n8.Press 8 to Exit");
 printf("\n\nEnter the Choice: ");
 scanf("%d",&ch);
 switch(ch)
 {
  case 1:
 add();
 break;

case 2:
printf("\nEnter the Roll No. : ");
scanf("%d",&r);
delAt(r);
break;

case 3:
printf("\nEnter the ID : ");
scanf("%d",&r);
modAt(r);
break;

case 4:
printf("\nEnter the Initials : ");
scanf("%s",&ni);
search(ni);
break;

case 5:
sort();
printf("\n\nSorted");
break;
case 6:
disp();
break;
 }
 getch();
    } 
   getch();  
  }
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step the code through line by line and see where it hangs? Also using a bit better named variables than one letter makes things a lot easier to read by others, as well as indenting the code nicely.

Comment: Please decide on an indentation scheme and apply it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the head is the item that need to be deleted which is done by:

```
if(q->rn == r && q == h){
       h = h->next;
       delete q;
       q = h;
       continue;
   }
```

Then check whether other nodes matched except head then delete that item by using:

```
if((q->next->rn == r)
   {
       temp = q->next;
       q->next=q->next->next;
       printf("\n\nRecord Deleted.");
       delete temp;
   }
```

The complete delete function will be as follows:

```
void delAt(int r)
  {
  stud* temp;
  q=h;

  while(q!=NULL) {
   if(q->rn == r && q == h){
       h = h->next;
       delete q;
       q = h;
       continue;
   }

   if((q->next->rn == r)
   {
       temp = q->next;
       q->next=q->next->next;
       printf("\n\nRecord Deleted.");
       delete temp;
   }
  else
   printf("\n\nRecord Not Found.");

   q=q->next;
  }
 }
```

Also for reading string `&` is not required. For example:

```
scanf("%s",&p->in);
```

is incorrect. It will be:

```
scanf("%s", p->in);// without &
```

For sort function add one `NULL` checking during the compare:

```
if(q->next != NULL && stricmp(q->in,(q->next)->in)>0)
```

For complete code for sort function will be:

```
void sort()
{

    p=h;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        q=h;
        while(q!=NULL)
        {
            if(q->next != NULL && stricmp(q->in,(q->next)->in)>0)
            {
                strcpy(t->in,q->in);
                strcpy(t->na,q->na);
                t->id=q->id;
                t->rn=q->rn;
                t->ph=q->ph;
                strcpy(t->add,q->add);
                strcpy(t->d,q->d);


                strcpy(q->in,(q->next)->in);
                strcpy(q->na,(q->next)->na);
                q->id=  (q->next)->id;
                q->rn=  (q->next)->rn;
                q->ph=  (q->next)->ph;
                strcpy(q->add,(q->next)->add);
                strcpy(q->d,(q->next)->d);

                strcpy((q->next)->in,t->in);
                strcpy((q->next)->na,t->na);
                (q->next)->id = t->id;
                (q->next)->rn = t->rn;
                (q->next)->ph = t->ph;
                strcpy((q->next)->add,t->add);
                strcpy((q->next)->d,t->d);

            }
            q=q->next;
        }
        p=p->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well thankyou for the correction. I really appreciate it. Can i ask for more one more help? Its sorting function is not working too? Can you check that too?